# Is there something mad going on with Magento critical vulnerability scanner

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-upgrade, security-scan-tool

I upgraded my site to **Magento2.3** a few hours back, but I am getting emails every few minutes from other peoples servers telling me to install `SUPEE-5344` which I thought **was years old**, is there some hack just come into force on some old accounts?

I have examined the email headers to confirm they are coming from a wide array of servers - but they are going to be my **security scanner** login address (I use a totally separate one for admin on my **Magento install**)

Answer (score 1):

It’s a spam and scam. Do not follow the links delete emails
If you can block them on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, 799 in the last two days addressed to 9 different addresses in one of my domains.  The only working link in all the emails is to https_://update.magento.center/admin/?random_crap=

Obviously a phishing attempt